# Populate Reactive Form With Data From rxjs Store

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an angular 11 app that uses an rxjs store. One of the arrays in that store is of my user list (IAdminUser).

I want to populate a reactive form with the data retrieved from that store. The params passes an id of the user and so I have this:

```
public user: IAdminUser;

ngOnInit(): void {
this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
  this.id = +params['id'];
  
   this.store.select('userAuth').subscribe(t => {
    this.user = t.adminUsers.find(t => t.userId == params['id']);
  },
  error => console.log(error),
  () => { console.log('complete store select')});
```

when I try and populate my form though the user is not returned as it only returns an observable. I have tried putting it in the completed section but this never gets triggered. When I put it inside the 'next' section it never has the user object defined, i.e.

```
this.store.select('userAuth').subscribe(t => {
    this.user = t.adminUsers.find(t => t.userId == params['id']);
    this.userDetailsForm = this.fb.group({
      userId: [this.user.userId, Validators.required],
      userName: [this.user.userName, Validators.required],
```

will say that user is undefined.

Is there a way to populate my form with the data returned from the store?

Comment: The code doesn't show that the property "user" has been defined.  Can you show us that part?

Comment: done It's a simple declaration

Comment: @GrahamJRoy should be number comparison =>  this.user = t.adminUsers.find(t => t.userId === +params['id']);

Comment: thanks. you answered my other problem of why === wasn't working and I put in == just to test

Comment: Take a look here hopefully it makes this easy to do :) https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, do not write subscribe in subscribe. And never create form group in a subscribe. Because every time when data changes, you will create a new form. You can create a form and rest the data every time needed.
So the code will be like:

- Create a form group
- Create user stream (user$) based on params and store.
- Reset form data every time user$ changes.

```
this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
    userId: ['', Validators.required],
    userName: ['', Validators.required],
});

const user$ = this.route.params.pipe(
    map(params => params['id']),
    withLatestFrom(this.store.select('userAuth')),
    map(([userId, userAuth]) => userAuth.adminUsers.find(user => user.userId = userId)),
);

user$.subscribe(user => {
    this.formGroup.reset(user);
});
```